# Make plugin working on only one specific page or page template

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've installed welcome message for wordpress.It is like a text or image on the intro which is fading out after some seconds automatically and it has no option to set it only on a main page or other pages. I'm interesed in how  make the plugin not working on all pages, except one(maybe functions.php) . Will be happy for every answer.THANKS!!!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/welcome/

```
   function welcome_output (){
    global $wDefaults;
    $wVar = welcome_getOptions();

    if($_COOKIE[$wDefaults['welcome_cookie_name']] == '1') return;

    echo '<div id="cover" style="background-color: ' .$wVar['welcome_color']. ';height:100%;width:100%; position:fixed;z-index:2147483646; top: 0; margin: 0 auto; left:0;">' . $wVar['welcome_content'] . '</div><noscript><style>#cover{ display: none; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px; }</style></noscript>';

    /* JS generation, mess */
    echo '<script> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){';
    if($wVar['welcome_cookie_duration'] > 0) 
        echo 'if(jQuery.cookie("'.$wDefaults['welcome_cookie_name'].'")=="1") return;';
    echo 'setTimeout(function() { jQuery("#cover").fadeOut('. ($wVar['welcome_sec_fade_out'] * 1000) .'); }, '. ($wVar['welcome_sec_after'] * 1000) .');

            jQuery.cookie("'.$wDefaults['welcome_cookie_name'] .'", "1", { expires: '. $wVar['welcome_cookie_duration']  .' });
    }); </script>';

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-cookie', plugins_url('/jquery.cookie.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.4.1', false );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wordpress function is_home().

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

If you want another page and not index. You can use is_page($pageid)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Comment: I'm noob in coding so I didn't understand you well^^ I need to add this line in my plugin php file? Can you give me more infromation please. THANKS!!!

Comment: Yes you have to insert the function into your main plugin php file. You need a if-clause.. like if(is_home()){ ###your php code###}

Comment: THANKS!!! But this code looks strange , Can I add it to a question and maybe you can tell me where to input it?:s anyway THANKS !!!!!!

Comment: I attached code into a question is this that code I need to edit?There is only one php file welcome.php and this is at the end, at the top I think it is admin panel options

Comment: I see it. I think you have to include the if-clause into this function "welcome_output" than it only output a welcome massage if the page is the index.

Comment: I edited code into the question, I think you are talking about this lines yeap?^^THANKS

Comment: Yes. before the global variable you input the if-clause and all your code is in the if-clause.

Comment: I added this    if(is_page('bio'))  global $wDefaults; etc.. and it still loading everywhere. Maybe this plugin have extra options we didnt know. Anyway BIG BIG THANKS!!!

Comment: Try to use the page ID and not the page Title. e.g. is_page(123)

Comment: it doesn't react((( strange plugin.. No answers from plugin authors also:D Hope will find another way to do similar . THANK YOU BRO!!! <3

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using the following code.

```
if (is_page('page-name')){
  // you code here
}
```

Comment: We tried up in the comments , you can see.Doesn't work((((( THANKS!

Comment: you can add shortcode hook like `add_shortcode('specificpage' , ' welcome_output');` and then `echo do_shortcode('[welcome_output ]')` where you want to show

Comment: First i need to turn off it everywhere and after add this shortcode. But I dont know how to turn off intro everywhere:D THANKS!